# Can't get text to wrap/break in product catalog

Tags: html, css, text, magento2, responsive

In items with longer product titles the text fails to wrap/break when the screen is resized and overlaps. Ive used word-wrap, white-space, word-break & overflow-wrap but the text refuses to break. See code below, you can also see the behavior on the site here: goo.gl/VsFBkx

```
.product-item-name {
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Work Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: normal !important;
}
styles-m.css:1
.product-item-name {
display: block;
margin: 5px 0;
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the webpage you linked, on line 188 of custom.css, you have this property:

```
a {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

That says that all links will refuse to wrap, and because the !important flag is there, it can't be overridden. Remove that and your link titles will wrap.

For future reference, I highly recommend you get familiar with the developer tools built into your web browser (google "[name of browser] developer tools"). It was very easy to find this issue using Chrome's dev tools.